# Авторизация с помощью CURL

Tags: curl, php

**Всем привет!**

Пытаюсь произвести авторизацию на сайте https://monitor.masterfolio.ru/auth/login в два шага: 1) получение исходного кода, 2) Вход на сайт :

```
$url = "https://monitor.masterfolio.ru/auth/login";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; En; rv:1.8.0.2) Gecko/20070306 Firefox/1.0.0.4");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$c = curl_exec($ch);

$c = mb_substr($c, mb_strpos($c,'login_csrf'), 70);
$c = mb_substr($c, mb_strpos($c,"=")+2);
$c = mb_substr($c, 0, mb_strpos($c,'"'));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  'http://site.loc/wordpress/cookie.txt'); // сохранять куки в файл 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'http://site.loc/wordpress/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "email=ctac4ever@gmail.com&password=test123&remember=1&login_csrf=".$c."&submit=1&formid=login");

$c = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $c;
```

Проблема вся в том, что в форме отправки запроса присутствует некое скрытое поле с динамическим хэшем, которое и мешает произвести отправку формы... Помогите мне, пожалуйста)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем, ключевая ошибка вот в чем: при входе на сайт создается сессия, в которую и сохраняется значение `login_csrf`, а значит куки надо сохранять с самого начала работы с сайтом.

Рабочий вариант:

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookiefile"); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; ru; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3'); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://monitor.masterfolio.ru/monitor'); 
    $html = curl_exec($curl);

    preg_match('/<input type="hidden" id="login_csrf" value="(.*)"/Uis',$html, $login_csrf);

    $login_csrf = $login_csrf[1];

    //echo $login_csrf;

    $post = "email=ctac4ever@gmail.com&password=test123&remember=1&login_csrf=".$login_csrf."&submit=Вход&formid=login";

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://monitor.masterfolio.ru/auth/login');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $html = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $html;
```

Comment: Ах, да, позабыл я про сессии совсем! Как вы это только выяснили? Спасибо вам огромное, все и правда работает!

---
Кроме того, у вас все очень изящно)

Comment: В процессе сравнения вашего кода со своим понял, что они отличаются лишь двумя вещами: 

     1) У вас работа с печеньем начинает в сааамом начале (кстати    говоря, без параметра CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION можно было бы обойтись )

     2) И вот этой повторной установкой: 
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,'https://monitor.masterfolio.ru/auth/login');

Answer (score 0):

так возмите значение скрытого поля в 1 ом шаге  и отправте его во 2-ом шаге

Comment: Еще раз просмотрите приведенный мною код....