# авторизация curl

Tags: php

Нашёл тему [Авторизация с помощью CURL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/176609/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-curl/176642#176642) но непонятно. у меня есть адрес где нужно авторизоваться, авторизацию хочу сквозную т.к в домене. (если через браузер на сайт зайти то автоматом тебя узнает, если локально зайти простит ввести логин domen\user). Суть проблемы в том что на 
оперделённый адрес посылаю запрос POST пример, но сервак пишет вы не авторизованы {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request.  Как в начале авторизоваться сохранить сессию и уже подпихнуть запрос?

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init("https://helpdesk.*****.ru:80**/inframanager/sdApi/registerCallEngineer");
// Передача данных осуществляется методом POST
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// Задаем POST-данные
$data = 'UserID=b105380a-389c-4c1d-842f-b5ce4c229d5b62197abe66de';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
// Выполняем запрос и выводим ответ в браузер
curl_exec($curl);
// Закрываем CURL соединение
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Comment: Читайте про использование CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR для сохранения и пере-использования выданных вам печенек (CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE) до и после авторизации (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте этот код:

```
$username='ABC';
$password='XYZ';
$URL='<URL>';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
curl_close ($ch);
```

Источник: [How to use basic authorization in PHP curl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20064360/7199362), [Suhel Meman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1503850/suhel-meman)